# Greatest of three numbers using switch case

Tags: java, bluej

I want to find out the greatest number, out of three given numbers, using switch-case(without using if)
I answered the question using this program, which works:

```
class GreatestNoSwitch{
    public int main(int a, int b, int c){
        int d = (int)Math.floor(a/b);
        int max = 0;
        switch(d){
            case 0:
                max = b;
                break;
            default:
                max = a;
        }

        d = (int)Math.floor(max/c);

        switch(d){
            case 0:
                max = c;
        }
        return max;
    }
}
```

Does anyone have any simpler answer?

Comment: What is your question? Is your code working?

Comment: StackOverflow is `Question` & `Answering` site. Post a `question` and we'll try to find an answer or at least help you finding an asnwer.

Comment: Without constraning what functions are allowed, this question doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's kinda stupid, but here you go.

```
switch(1)
{
    default:
        return Math.max(a, Math.max(b, c));
}
```

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik - better?

Comment: Why would it be better? You are still using variables in `case` clauses.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik - only constants... I see.  This is a stupid puzzle anyway, and my answer is equally stupid.  So they fit!

Comment: A perfect fit indeed! That's exactly what I meant when I said that without constraints on allowed functions, the puzzle is stupid.

Comment: I now feel hat this was a stupid puzzle... Thanks

Comment: @YogeshAgar - only in its current state, but could be the start of a great puzzle if you could figure out the limitations to make people think.  I'm not sure that adding a rule like "without using a default case" would be solvable, but give it a shot.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you want to write the world's most complex snippet of code to find the max of three integers.   This one is more readable, yet still complex enough to keep you amused...

```
public int main( int a, int b, int c)
{
    return Collections.max( Arrays.asList( new Integer[]{a,b,c} ));
}
```